# Excel on PC and Thin Client

Tags: excel, validation

I have produced an Excel file with various macros, data validations, calculations etc on a normal PC.  However when opened on a thin client, one of the data validation drop down lists disappears.  The list is supposed to be:

```
=AE!$A:$A
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this so it doesn't disappear?

Comment: I'm on 2010.  Some are 2007 and 2003 though...

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work this one out.  I created the file in the 2007 version, then it worked fine for both 2010 and 2007 systems.